# How do you write to a pre-existing nested dictionary within a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm testing storing data with JSON files using python, however I don't seem to be able to write the data within a nested dictionary. It's hard to explain so hopefully the code will help.

```
import json


def write():

    usernameInput = input("Enter a username: \n")
    emailInput = input("Enter an email: \n")
    passwordInput = input("Enter a password: \n")
    nameInput = input("Enter your name: \n")
    dobInput = input("Enter your DOB (DD/MM/YYYY): \n")
    pastaInput = input("Do you like pasta? Y/N: \n")

    if pastaInput == "Y":
        likesPasta = True
    elif pastaInput == "N":
        likesPasta = False
    else:
        likesPasta = None

    userkey = usernameInput.lower()
    users = {"users": {userkey: {}}} #This uses the same format of nested dict as the JSON does


    users["users"][userkey]["username"] = usernameInput #This is how I set the variables for the nested Dict
    users["users"][userkey]["email"] = emailInput
    users["users"][userkey]["password"] = passwordInput
    users["users"][userkey]["name"] = nameInput
    users["users"][userkey]["dob"] = dobInput
    users["users"][userkey]["likespasta"] = likesPasta

    json_file = open("json_path_here", "w") #I have tried open modes "a" and "w" but neither work ("a" just makes a new dict in the json and "w" overwrites everything *duh*)
    json.dump(users, json_file)
    json_file.close()
```

The JSON file:

```
{
   "users": {
      "a": {
         "username": "a",
         "email": "b",
         "password": "c",
         "name": "d",
         "dob": "e",
         "likespasta": null
      }
   }
}
```

I want the output JSON to look like this when I add a new person (person b)

```
{
   "users": {
      "a": {
         "username": "a",
         "email": "b",
         "password": "c",
         "name": "d",
         "dob": "e",
         "likespasta": null
      },
      "b":{
         "username": "d",
         "email": "ve",
         "password": "dasd",
         "name": "sad",
         "dob": "cs",
         "likespasta": true
      }
   }
}
```

But it ends up like this:

```
{
   "users": {
      "a": {
         "username": "a",
         "email": "b",
         "password": "c",
         "name": "d",
         "dob": "e",
         "likespasta": null
      }
   }
}
   "users": {
      "b": {
         "username": "b",
         "email": "ve",
         "password": "dasd",
         "name": "sad",
         "dob": "cs",
         "likespasta": true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi :) It seems like your code should work fine. It would be nice if you provide more specific information about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify your expected and actual output? All you are showing is code to write JSON to a file, without making it clear how this is not what you want.

Comment: @NicolasIceberg I've added my output and expectations :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I've added my output and expectations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you, I modified your code quite a bit to make it a bit more simple:

```
import json
import os


def pasta_parse(answer):
    valid_answers = {
        'y': True,
        'n': False
    }
    # return none if not in valid_answers
    return valid_answers.get(answer.lower()) # convert to lower to match


def get_answers():
    return [{
        'username': input('Enter a username: \n'),
        'email': input('Enter an email: \n'),
        'password': input('Enter a password: \n'),
        'name': input('Enter your name: \n'),
        'dob': input('Enter your DOB (DD/MM/YYYY): \n'),
        'pasta': pasta_parse(input('Do you like pasta? Y/N: \n')) # <-- cool
    }]


def write_json(path, data, indent=4):
    with open(path,'w') as file: 
        json.dump(data, file, indent=indent) 


def append_json(path, data, key=None):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        write_json(path, data)
    else:
        with open(path) as file:
            # load a dict of th edata
            json_data = json.load(file)
            # key should be a list of objects so you can __add__ them
            if key is None:
                json_data += data
            else:
                json_data[key] += data
            write_json(path, json_data)


# declare blank users list, we can add list(dict) to this without appending
users = []

# add get_answers to users
# if you had any more code earlier using this,
# you may have to do this data structure differently
users += get_answers()

append_json('user.json', users)
```

This will ask you the questions each time you run the script and append/create the json file. I modified your data structure a little bit to have an array at the root of the json by default but that can be changed and you can specify a key at the root of your json to save the array to. You may have to change the code a bit if you have other data at the root of your json file.

I ran the code a few times and got this json:

```
[
    {
        "username": "asdf",
        "email": "asdf",
        "password": "asdf",
        "name": "asdf",
        "dob": "asdfasdfasdf",
        "pasta": false
    },
    {
        "username": "asdfasdfasdf",
        "email": "sadfasdfasdf",
        "password": "asdfsadfasdfas",
        "name": "asdf",
        "dob": "asdfasdfas",
        "pasta": true
    },
    {
        "username": "asdfasdcasder",
        "email": "gfhnfgyi",
        "password": "srrtybzdt",
        "name": "sdrtfb",
        "dob": "",
        "pasta": null
    }
]
```